# How to show/hide button with switch that saves value in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I have **UISwitch** named **sosSwitch** thas saves value in **NSUserDefaults** key: **MySwitch** and I have **UIButton** named **sosBtn**.
How can I show/hide **sosBtn** depending on the switch value that was saved in **NSUserDefaults**? And where I need to put the code? In viewDidLoad? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you already have:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *sosBtn;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *sosSwich;
- (IBAction)sosSwitch:(id)sender;
```

Try this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{    
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"MySwitch"])
    {
        self.sosBtn.hidden = NO;
        [self.sosSwich setOn:YES animated:YES]; 
    }
    else 
    {
        self.sosBtn.hidden = YES;
        [self.sosSwich setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }
}

- (IBAction)sosSwitch:(id)sender 
{
    UISwitch *mySosSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    if (mySosSwitch.on)
    {
        self.sosBtn.hidden = NO;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"MySwitch"];  //YES means sosBtn should be visible
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    else 
    {
        self.sosBtn.hidden = YES;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"MySwitch"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand.. but if my switch located in modal view controller and button in view, how can I do the same?

Comment: In that case you will need to implement the optional delegate method.  Check out my answer to this SO that had an example of delegate method callback.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606674/uimodaltransitionstylepartialcurl-doesnt-get-back-to-previous-state-not-dismi/8607949#8607949