# iOS Communication between Model and ViewController

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

I am developing an app based on the Master-View template provided by Apple (it consists of two ViewControllers, the MasterViewController and the DetailViewController). I have added a Model for communication with my server.

However, when my Model receives a message from the server, it needs to call a method in the MasterViewController or DetailViewController class. How can I do this?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your model? Model for M in MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could fire notifications from the model, which are handled by the Master and Detail View controllers.

**In the model:**

```
- (void)receivedMessageFromServer {
    // Fire the notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReceivedData" 
                                                        object:nil];   
}
```

**Handle the "ReceivedData" notification in your View Controller(s):**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                            selector:@selector(receivedDataNotification:) 
                                                name:@"ReceivedData" 
                                              object:nil];
}

- (void)receivedDataNotification:(id)object {
    NSLog(@"Received Data!");
}
```

Comment: But how do I send a string through NSNotifications? it seems all I am able to do is send an empty notification

Comment: use the object parameter. I'm passing it nil in the example above, but you can pass in any object like you, including NSStrings.

Comment: question :) - should I use notification or delegate? I saw in the answers that delegate is suggested too. Which way is better?

Comment: notification is better, because in this way the MVC conversation rules are not violated. Model just broadcasts a notification and the view controller just chooses to receive it, as supposed to delegate where you would actually let the Model weakly get ahold of the view controller, which is a bad design. View controllers should talk to Models actively, not the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the [MVC pattern that Apple proposes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) allows for notifications from the model to the controller.

A good way to achieve this goal could be to deliver [NSNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) objects through the [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) when your data changes, with information on what is changed, and let the listeners take care of it.

Comment: But how do I send a string through NSNotifications? it seems all I am able to do is send an empty notification

Comment: Please refer to [Apple's documentation on NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  You can assign a name and a sender object to your notification with `- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender`.

Comment: For example you could have the data object be the sender, and the notification name could be a string such as: `@"senderNamePropertyChanged"` (I recommend that you use constants to define allowed notification names).

Comment: I realized I can use the optional UserInfo argument.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the optional protocol delegate method.  I have an answer with example how to setup delegate method in this [PO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606674/uimodaltransitionstylepartialcurl-doesnt-get-back-to-previous-state-not-dismi/8607949#8607949).

Answer (score 1):

Blocks are the way to go.

You need to have a reference to your model in ViewController. When you want to update data you send a message to the model and pass block as a parameter to it which would get called when the response is received from server.

For example:

**View Controller**

```
[self.model fetchDataFromRemoteWithCompletionHandler:^(id responseObject, NSError *error)
{
    // responseObject is the Server Response
    // error - Any Network error
}];
```

**Model**

```
-(void)fetchDataFromRemoteWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(id, NSError*))onComplete
{
    // Make Network Calls
    // Process Response
    // Return data back through block
    onComplete(foobarResponse, error);
}
```