# how to resume timer when poping to view2

Tags: ios, xcode, nstimer

my application has 3 views

in view1 only one button (play level 1) that pushes to veiw2 and updates titlelabel in view2

when view2 loads and appears a timer starts to count down and update another label in view2 itself, also view2 has button that pauses the timer and pushes to view3

in view3 only one button that pop back to view2 and resumes thee timer

my problem is that when i pop from view3 to view2 the timer is still paused

any help please?

Thanks & kind regards.

view1.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface view1 : UIViewController





-(IBAction)nextpage;

@end
```

view1.m

```
#import "view1.h"
#import "view2.h"
@interface view1 ()

@end

@implementation view1




-(IBAction)nextpage{

    view2 *obj = [[view2 alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
    [obj.leveltitle setText:@"Level"];
    obj.time=10;  

}




- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

view2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface view2 : UIViewController



{
    int time;
    NSTimer *timer;
    BOOL paused;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) int time;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL paused;


@property (readwrite, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *leveltitle;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) IBOutlet UILabel *label;



-(IBAction)back;
-(IBAction)pause;


@end
```

view2.m

```
#import "view2.h"
#import "view3.h"
@interface view2 ()

@end

@implementation view2

@synthesize leveltitle, label;
@synthesize time, timer;
@synthesize paused;

-(void)countDown2
{
    if (paused == NO && time>0) 
 {
        time = time -1 ;
     view3 *obj = [[view3 alloc] init];
     obj.sss = time;
    if (time == 0)
 {
            [timer invalidate];    

 }

        [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",time]];
 }


}


-(IBAction)back{

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


-(IBAction)pause{

     view3 *obj = [[view3 alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
     paused = YES;   
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    paused = NO;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self     selector:@selector(countDown2) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];



    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

view3.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface view3 : UIViewController

{

    int sss;
}

@property (nonatomic) int sss;
-(IBAction)back;


@end
```

view3.m

```
#import "view3.h"
#import "view2.h"
@interface view3 ()

@end

@implementation view3
@synthesize sss;

-(IBAction)back{

    view2 *obj = [[view2 alloc] init];
    obj.paused=NO;
    obj.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self     selector:@selector(cont) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
     //[obj.timer fire];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}



 -(void)cont{
     view2 *obj = [[view2 alloc] init];
     obj.time = sss;
     if (obj.paused == NO && time>0) 
     {
         obj.time = obj.time -1 ;

         if (obj.time == 0)
         {
             [obj.timer invalidate];    

         }

         [obj.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",obj.time]];
     }



 }


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because in `view3`'s `back` method, you created a new instant of `view2` name `obj` and set `paused=NO`.  But that `obj` was not the same instant of `view2` when you pop back.  What you need to do is to use a delegate method pattern, so that `view3` will have a callback  method in `view2` to set the `paused` to `NO`.

For an example of delegate method pattern, check out an example from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606674/uimodaltransitionstylepartialcurl-doesnt-get-back-to-previous-state-not-dismi/8607949#8607949).

Edit: sample callback code:

Make these addition/changes to your code:

In view2.h:

```
#import "view3.h"

@interface view2 : UIViewController <view3Delegate>
```

In view2.m:

```
-(IBAction)pause{

    view3 *obj = [[view3 alloc] init];
    obj.delegate = self;  //adding this line
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
    paused = YES;   
}

-(void)setPausedValue:(BOOL)value   //this is the new method callback from view3 to set paused value
{
    paused = value;
}
```

In view3.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol view3Delegate <NSObject>
-(void) setPausedValue:(BOOL)value;
@end
@interface view3 : UIViewController
{
    int sss;
}
@property (assign) id <view3Delegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic) int sss;
-(IBAction)back;
@end
```

In view3.m:

```
@implementation view3
@synthesize delegate;

-(IBAction)back{

//    view2 *obj = [[view2 alloc] init];  
//    obj.paused=NO;
    [self.delegate setPausedValue:NO];  //make callback and set value
    obj.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self     selector:@selector(cont) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    //[obj.timer fire];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: actually I'm new to xcode, sorry but couldn't quite get your answer. would you please explain more. I somehow understood that obj was not the same instant of view2 but couldn't create a delegate method as shown in the example you put link to.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, your code helped me so much, actually it solved my problem.