# UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl does not trigger ViewWillAppear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using UIReferenceLibraryViewController and would like to play sound when it is dismissed. I am calling my sound in my main controller's viewWillAppear event. However if I change UIReferenceLibraryViewController ModalTransitionStyle style to UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl, viewWillAppear is not triggered. Is there any other way I can capture its dismissal?

Comment: I would use a delegate pattern.  Here is an [sample][1] with similar task. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606674/uimodaltransitionstylepartialcurl-doesnt-get-back-to-previous-state-not-dismi/8607949#8607949

Comment: I am not dismissing UIReferenceLibraryViewController myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense that your main controller's `viewWillAppear` method is not called with `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` when the `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` is dismissed because your main controller's view was never completely removed from the screen. What you really are interested in is when the `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` is dismissed, not when your main controller appears so structure your code accordingly. That is, subclass `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` and put your sound playing into the subclass's `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`. This will work for any transition style.

Comment: Glad it works for you. Be sure to check the gray checkmark next to the answer if so. That way others know the question is answered.

Comment: would you have a syntax example on how you would do that?