# How to change the background color from another ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-color

I have two view controllers, the Home and the other that is showed by a cocoacontrol animation (MJPopupViewController) and idn the one that is showed when you push a button all the background changes, but I dont know how to change the home view controller`s background because they are not in a navigation so I cant use a self.parentViewController casting, so how can I do this? Heres the code:

```
- (IBAction)purple:(id)sender {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor MyPurple];

    HomeViewController *home = (HomeViewController *) self.parentViewController; <-- this didnt work, I also tried only self....

    home.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];


}
```

So I need your help, Im starting so I hope you understand, thanks!

Comment: Use a delegate pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606674/uimodaltransitionstylepartialcurl-doesnt-get-back-to-previous-state-not-dismi/8607949#8607949

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try:

HomeViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(changeColor)
     name:@"changeColor" object:nil];
}

- (void)changeColor
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
}
```

PopUpViewController

```
- (IBAction)purple:(id)sender
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"changeColor" object:nil];
}
```

Comment: mmm no didnt work, I dont know if its that but theres no navigation controller...

Comment: Well, that will be the issue. You need to get the index to the view controller in the heirarchy.

Comment: Sorry but if its not too much trouble how can I do that? Its because Im starting and I dont get it.. Thanks

Comment: Well, are you using some kind of container view controller or a tab bar controller? How are your controllers being added to the stack?

Comment: With this UIViewController Category https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController

Comment: Have you tried using an NSNotification to change the background color? That will work

Comment: Thank you so much! I know I needed an observer but i didnt know how to write it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change the background color of a 'view' you need to set the backgroundColor property on it. This implies that you have access to it. If it was all in one controller you would just use

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

If it was in a navigation or similar based app, then you can access a views parentViewController and change the color on it as follows:

```
self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

If this is not possible then you can set an iVar on the second view controller when it is created that contains the instance of the viewController that you want to change the background color on.

```
MyViewController* secondViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
secondViewController.bgColorNeedsChangingViewController = self;
```

Then in the secondViewController's logic

```
self.bgColorNeedsChangingViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```